# 2sxc - Cannot use c# vars

Tags: c#, linq, razor, 2sxc

I'm trying to use a 2sxc view to create some statistics with linq. However I can't seem to be able to call any c# var. Here's an example:

```
@{
    if (@Request.QueryString["ano"] == "" || @Request.QueryString["ano"] == null) {
        <p>ano not set, using current year (@DateTime.Now.Year)</p>
        var year = @DateTime.Now.Year;
        } else {
        <p>ano set (@Request.QueryString["ano"])</p>
        var year = @Request.QueryString["ano"];
    }

    var items = AsDynamic(App.Data["entity"]);
    items = items.Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.data_a).Year == year);
}
```

This results in

```
error CS0103: The name 'year' does not exist in the current context
```

Am I doing something really stupid again?

Comment: Your `year` variable declared in inner scope. Move it decalration above `if` statement

Comment: I don't quite get it... Shouldn't it be the same? var x= 1 and if (1=1) {var x=1}? Nevertheless, it works. Adding int year = 0; at the top and adapting requests to int fixed it. Thanks (would you please also post your comment as an answer to mark it solved?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring variable inside `if` statement and referencing it outside `if`
Now you can rewrite you code like this:

```
@{
    int year = 0;
    if (@Request.QueryString["ano"] == "" || @Request.QueryString["ano"] == null) {
        <p>ano not set, using current year (@DateTime.Now.Year)</p>
        year = @DateTime.Now.Year; // no "var" keyword here!
        } else {
        <p>ano set (@Request.QueryString["ano"])</p>
        year = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ano"]);
    }

    var items = AsDynamic(App.Data["entity"]);
    items = items.Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.data_a).Year == year);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a small fix: year = Int32.Parse(@Request.QueryString["ano"]);

Comment: @JoãoGomes yep, you a right. By the way `int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ano"])` is also working. I will edit my answer